# Form Post with Data for Multiple Tables

Tags: html

I have a html page used for updating data on an car that has multiple tables represented in one form. I want to dynamically update the tables with input elements providing a value that identifies the table the data belongs too.

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="engineType" name="engineType" value="V8">
```

Using the above example the post would allow me to identify the input being associated with the engine table without having to split the id or name in the server code. I have in the past used the id or name field with a colon separating pieces of information i.e. id="engineType:engine" then splitting at the colon.

In html5 is there a better way of passing this data? For instance I was looking for a hint attribute but did not not find that available.

Comment: No, HTML5 has nothing new in terms of form processing.

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to make sure I was not missing something.